# Comprobar usuario repetido en BD SQL en Android Studio

Tags: java, android, sql, android-studio

He hecho una función que registra los usuarios en una base de datos. Lo que quiero hacer ahora es que si un usuario nuevo registra un nickname con el mismo nombre que uno que ya está en la BD le salga un mensaje que le diga que el usuario ya existe.

```
private void registrarUsuario() {
    UsuariosDbHelper conn = new UsuariosDbHelper(this, "bd_usuario", null, 1);
    SQLiteDatabase db = conn.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Utilidades.USUARIO, campoUsuario.getText().toString());
    values.put(Utilidades.CONTRASENYA, campoContrasenya.getText().toString());
    values.put(Utilidades.NOMBRE, campoNombre.getText().toString());
    values.put(Utilidades.EDAD, campoEdad.getText().toString());
    values.put(Utilidades.CIUDAD, campoCiudad.getText().toString());
    values.put(Utilidades.CODIGOPOSTAL, campoCodPostal.getText().toString());
    values.put(Utilidades.SEXO, campoSexo.getText().toString());
    values.put(Utilidades.PAIS, campoPais.getText().toString());

    long resultado = db.insert(Utilidades.TABLA_USUARIO, Utilidades.NOMBRE, values);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "resultado: " + resultado, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    db.close();
}
```

Esta es la función que registra los usuarios en la BD.

```
botonGuardar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String usuarioComprobar = campoUsuario.getText().toString();
        String contrasenyaComprobar = campoContrasenya.getText().toString();
        String nombreComprobar = campoNombre.getText().toString();
        String edadComprobar = campoEdad.getText().toString();
        String ciudadComprobar = campoCiudad.getText().toString();
        String codPComprobar = campoCodPostal.getText().toString();
        String paisComprobar = campoPais.getText().toString();
        String sexoComprobar = campoSexo.getText().toString();

        if (isNullorEmpty(usuarioComprobar) || isNullorEmpty(contrasenyaComprobar) || isNullorEmpty(nombreComprobar) || isNullorEmpty(edadComprobar) || isNullorEmpty(ciudadComprobar) ||
                isNullorEmpty(codPComprobar) || isNullorEmpty(paisComprobar) || isNullorEmpty(sexoComprobar)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Debes insertar todos los datos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            registrarUsuario();
        }
    }
});
```

Este es el botón con el que se guardan los usuarios.

```
public static boolean isNullorEmpty(String cadena) {
    return (cadena == null || cadena.trim().isEmpty());
}
```

Función isNullorEmpty

Se agradece la ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te dejo un ejemplo:

```
botonGuardar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String usuarioComprobar = campoUsuario.getText().toString();
        String contrasenyaComprobar = campoContrasenya.getText().toString();
        String nombreComprobar = campoNombre.getText().toString();
        String edadComprobar = campoEdad.getText().toString();
        String ciudadComprobar = campoCiudad.getText().toString();
        String codPComprobar = campoCodPostal.getText().toString();
        String paisComprobar = campoPais.getText().toString();
        String sexoComprobar = campoSexo.getText().toString();
        // declaras un int para poder utilizarlo en la validación:
        int notificar = 0;

        if (isNullorEmpty(usuarioComprobar) || isNullorEmpty(contrasenyaComprobar) || isNullorEmpty(nombreComprobar) || isNullorEmpty(edadComprobar) || isNullorEmpty(ciudadComprobar) ||
                isNullorEmpty(codPComprobar) || isNullorEmpty(paisComprobar) || isNullorEmpty(sexoComprobar)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Debes insertar todos los datos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            // entras a la base de datos con un Cursor. Agrega 2 String para hacer la comparación:
            UsuariosDbHelper conn = new UsuariosDbHelper(this, "bd_usuario", null, 1);
            SQLiteDatabase db = conn.getWritableDatabase();
            String usuarioNuevo = nombreComprobar;
            String uruarioRegistrado;

            Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + Utilidades.TABLA_USUARIO, null);

            if(c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    // en este caso verifica todos los strings de la columna NOMBRE:
                    usuarioRegistrado = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Utilidades.NOMBRE));
                    // y comparas si ya existe el nombre
                    if(usuarioRegistrado.equals(usuarioNuevo)) {
                        notificar = 1;
                    }
                } while(c.moveToNext());
            }

            // if/else anidado:
            if(notificar == 1) {
                // y agregas el Toast o Snackbar
                Snackbar.make(v, "El Usuario ya existe", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "El Usuario ya existe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                registrarUsuario();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: el que dio -1 podría opinar porque?

Comment: bueno yo no he sido, pero no esta bien tu respuesta, ya que estan escribiendo "conn.getWritableDatabase();"cuando tienes que leer "conn.getReadbleDatabase()", eso lo primero. y tener separado el leer de escribir, y ya que tienes un metodo para cosa, mejor tener los dos separado etc etc,
copy and paste de lo mio, pero bueno, no creo que quien intente usar eso le funcione correctamente.
Salu2

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo de distintas formas, con un método aparte que te devuelva un bolean, donde tienes el `if` que compruebas si ha rellenado los datos, pones un `else if` y o llamas a un método o lo haces dentro,
algo así te serviría:

```
public boolean compararUsuario(String usuarioBuscado) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = conn.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = null;
    String nombreUsuario;
    boolean usuarioExiste= false;

    try {
        cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT usuario FROM Usuarios where usuario = ?", new String[]{usuarioBuscado});
        if(cursor != null && cursor .moveToFirst()) {
            nombreUsuario = cursor.getString(0); 
            
            usuarioExiste = true;
            cursor.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        cursor.close();
    }

    return usuarioExiste; 
}
```

Cambia la consulta con tus datos, pero seria algo muy parecido a eso
espero que te sirva. Después tendrías que ver si `compararUsuarios = false`, no insertas el usuario y muestras que el usuario ya existe.